# When did Sasuke awaken his Mangekyo Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

When did Sasuke awaken his Mangekyo Sharingan? What is his actual MS ability before Itachi's death?

Comment: naruto wiki perhaps...

Comment: [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan#Sasuke_Uchiha) has the answer. Tried to put some effort (like, googling) before asking on here...

Answer (score 1):

Before itachi’s death, sasuke could show a powerful genjutsu to his enemies with his sharingan, and before he defeated itachi and killed him, itachi transfered his power to sasuke. and then sasuke learnes the truth about why itachi betrayed the hidden leaf villiage, and then he gets mad and sad, and Then Sasuke awkens his mangekyo sharingan, and then he learnes how to use his new power, and then he obtaines the amatarasu and the susano’o